# How can I build array for my Hour

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to check URL by pass the latest hour and minute. 
hour --> current hour --> 0 .. 23 
minute --> fix 4 elements: {5, 10, 15, 20} 
With my code following, I can only check for current hour but not for previous hour. How can I build array for my Hour ? Many Thanks

```
public int getMyTime() {
    Calendar calToday = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = calToday.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int[] minute = {5, 10, 15, 20};
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i=hour; i>=0; i--) {
        for (int j=minute.length; j>=0; j--) {
            String url = "http://abc="+hour+minute[j];
            if (Live(url) == true) {
                temp = hour+minute;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correct your inner for loop by setting j = minute.length - 1. By definition, your array indices will start at 0 and go to 3 since there are 4 elements. What is your getInstance() method doing? If you want to take each hour and each minute set your hour to 1 and increment it until it hits 12. Do that for minutes too, just increment it until 59. You can do a little bit of math to calculate whether it is a.m or p.m. You can use an array, it would just take more work because you have to store each hour and make your loop go through each element and pring what the hour is and what the minute is.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=hour; i>=0; i--) {
```

In here you are setting `i` to the current `hour` but in:

```
String url = "http://abc="+hour+minute[j];
```

and

```
temp = hour+minute;
```

you are using `hour` and not `i`.